# How to see iOS 10 logs from xcode lower than xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, logging

It was imposible for me to see any log in xcode 7 from my iPhone 7 with iOS 10.0.
I found out that you can see them only from xcode 8.

- Is it posible to see logs from devices with iOS 10 from a xcode
  version lower than 8 ?
- If yes then how ?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Try either of these options:

**1. Use iOS Console**

You can use iOS Console app on MacOS 10.12 where you can filter and can have exactly the logs which you care about.

**2. From XCode**

Open `Window -> Devices` from XCode, you can see device logs there. But it is hard to find out logs, it will print both device and all app logs.